# Ubuntu 14.04 lags after watching video on Internet

Tags: video

When I turn on my computer, everything works just fine, Ubuntu is perfect. But after watching some videos (both HTML5 videos on Youtube and Flash video) on Internet, it starts to lag. Could anyone tell me what to do? Thanks!

Comment: I've noticed this problem too. When I opened `System Monitor` I noticed that the `Xorg` process was taking about 5GB of RAM. Killing it fixed it for me. You'll be faced with a black, sometimes flashing screen for about a minute before the login screen comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Update your graphics driver. Check for additional drivers in Software & Updates or run this in teminal

> software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4